# Error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subscribers'

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a `GenericRelation` on a model called Book:

```
subscribers = GenericRelation(Subscriber)
```

So if I want to find all the subscribers to a Book I do this:

```
self.subscribers.all()
```

However, when I try to do the same on a queryset of books:

```
subscribers = queryset.subscribers.all()
```

I get the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subscribers'
```

Why? Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subscribers` relation is on the model, not on the queryset. You can iterate through the queryset, and get the subscribers for each individual instance.

```
for book in queryset:
    subscribers = book.subscribers.all()
```

If you want to fetch all subscribers that have subscribed to any book in the queryset, you need to set `related_query_name` (note, this only works in Django 1.7+).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    subscribers = GenericRelation(Subscriber, related_query_name=books)
```

You can then get the subscribers for the queryset with:

```
subscribers = Subscriber.objects.filter(books__in=queryset)
```

For more info, see the docs on [reverse generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The subscribers are only available on a per book basis. If you want to get all possible subscribers of a (query)set of books you would need retrieve them using a query like:

```
Subscriber.objects.filter(book__in=queryset)
```

You might want to add a `.distinct()` to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Note that because it's a generic relation, you need to set `related_query_name` before this will work.